# What is the Cardano Stiftung?

Tags: cardano-foundation

I have seen this mentioned a few times and have no idea what it is.
I get the impression that it is referring to the combination of the Cardano Foundation, IO Global and Emurgo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are synonyms. Stiftung is German for foundation. The Cardano Foundation is located in Zug, Switzerland - a German-speaking part of the country.

The twitter handle of the (now verified) Cardano Foundation is CardanoStiftung: https://twitter.com/CardanoStiftung.